# Is there a way to trigger context menu in TextInput component programmatically?

Tags: react-native

I want to trigger the context menu (copy and paste) in the TextInput programmatically in react native. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

yes, its possible. You can use react-native-popup-menu to show context menu and clipboard to copy/paste.